# retrieve column data in ListView

Tags: asp.net

how can i retrieve columns data from ListView in asp.net?

in C#  can use
listView1.SelectedItems[N].SubItems[X].Text;

But Subitems[X] Doesn't exist in ASP.Net

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Do you want to retrieve column names? Or just the data in each column?

Comment: just the data in each column...

Comment: What are you binding to the listview? What type is that data?

Comment: my listview is filling by a sqldatasource adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `FindControl`. For instance, if you have something like this in the aspx:

```
<ListView id="myListView" ...>
...
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="myText" />
 </ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

to get the text in *myText*, you can do this:

```
var text = ((TextBox) myListView.Items[0].FindControl("myText")).Text;
```